# How to display data for a specific month in a table？

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to know how to display data for a specific month in a table.

There is a table with the column [EmployeeId,Date,StartTime,EndTime].
I want to filter by the month of Date, but I don't know how.

```
  var AttendanceResult = [];

  // Select employee number and current month data
   var query = app.models.AttendanceMaster.newQuery(); 
   query.filters.EmployeeId._equals = userNumber;　// Match employee number
   query.filters.Date._contains = roadMonth;       // Including month

   var records = query.run();  

   for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
      AttendanceResult.push(records[i]);
   }   

return AttendanceResult;
```

Since the "query.filters.Date._contains = roadMonth;" filter in the above code is not working,
I think there is an error here,
Please tell me.

What are some examples of filters?

Comment: I’m actually not sure that the App Maker query options are built to handle a query for a month within a date field. You might want to explore calculated SQL models as regular SQL queries are able to filter by specific date portions such as month.

Comment: Thanks to Markus Malessa for advice. I will investigate the SQL query. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly use appmaker's scripting to achieve this. Building from your example, I see you are using server scripting. The following snippet should help you understand how to achieve it and should also yield the result you desire:

```
function filterByMonth(month){

  //get the selected month digit
  month = month.toLowerCase();
  var allMonths = {
    "january": 0,
    "february": 1,
    "march": 2,
    "april": 3,
    "may": 4,
    "june": 5,
    "july": 6,
    "august": 7,
    "september": 8,
    "october": 9,
    "november": 10,
    "december": 11
  };
  var monthDigit = allMonths[month];

  // Select employee number and current month data
  var selectedMonthStart = new Date();
  selectedMonthStart.setMonth(monthDigit);
  selectedMonthStart.setDate(1);
  selectedMonthStart.setHours(0,0,-1,0);
  var selectedMonthEnd = new Date();
  selectedMonthEnd.setMonth(monthDigit+ 1);
  selectedMonthEnd.setDate(1);
  selectedMonthEnd.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var query = app.models.AttendanceMaster.newQuery(); 
  query.filters.EmployeeId._equals = userNumber;　// Match employee number
  query.filters.Date._greaterThan = selectedMonthStart; // Including month start time
  query.filters.Date._lessThan = selectedMonthEnd; // Including month end time
  var AttendanceResult = query.run();

  return AttendanceResult; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it very much.
Based on the sample code, I was able to filter safely.
Thanks to you.