# How to query a datasource of type DateTime MY SQL in App Maker?

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I am making a server call querying a record using a datetime filter like follows:

```
query.filters.CreatedDate._greaterThan = new Date('2020-04-20 19:39:56');
```

CreateDate is type datetime on a mysql database. 
But when I run this query I get the following error:

> Expected Date for filtering by 'CreatedDate'.
>   Error: Expected Date for filtering by 'CreatedDate'.
>     at appStartUp (DashboardServer:77)

I have no idea why is there a type mismatch. I have also tried converting JS datetime to mysql datetime using the following and many other snippets but still I am recieving the same error.

```
new Date(); d.toISOString().split('T')[0]+' '+d.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display data for a specific month in a table？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58945570/how-to-display-data-for-a-specific-month-in-a-table)

Comment: @Morfinismo No, the problem seems to be that the Date object created by ' new Date() ' function is not returning a recognizable date format for the query and I dont understand why. Does the solution imply that I have to set the day, month, year one by one manually after creating the Date object?

Comment: Are you using [datasources](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources) or a My SQL [external database](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/external-data-options)? If it's the latter you should use [jdbc service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) to make the connection and [newTime()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#newtimemilliseconds) method to create a JdbcTime object.